# logging while doing xslt transformation .NET

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xslt

Is there any way to do logging (of errors, information) while doing XSLT transformation( from one xml to another based on XSL language)?

Comment: Well, which .NET XSLT processor do you use exactly, Microsoft has two, `XslTransform` and `XslCompiledTransform`, then there is `XmlPrime`, there is the .NET version of Saxon 9, there is Altova with a .NET API. Inside XSLT you can use `xsl:message`, how you handle that in your .NET code depends on the processor's API.

Comment: I am using XslTransform

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xsltmessageencounteredeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx on how you can capture `xsl:message`s with `XslCompiledTransform`, I am not sure whether that approach works also with `XslTransform`, you might want to try.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for